# Consensus on another user posting another answer in the same language

Tags: discussion

Should another user post another answer, instead of commenting, in a language that already has answers from somebody else, in the following circumstances?

1. It is a modified version of the current answer.
2. It uses an entirely different algorithm, etc.
3. Part of the new answer is a derivation from the first one, and part of the new answer utilizes another algorithm.

My personal idea is **No** for the first one and **Yes** for the second one. However, what about the third one?

Notice I'm not discussing copyright here.

Do we already have a consensus on this? I cannot find up-to-date posts after a bit of research. The only thing I come up with is [mniip's idea](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/second-answer-for-second-language) from 2014.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/42963).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don’t think there can be a consensus on this because it highly depends about the initial and new answers.

I personally do the following:

#### Comment but don’t post a new answer

- if the improvement is fairly straightforward for someone that knows the language well and was overlooked by the author.
- If the improvement uses language quirks that the author might not have known but don’t fundamentally change the algorithm used initially.

#### Post a new answer, but cite the original answer

- If I came up with my answer after looking at the original one, and part of my answer is directly inspired / copied from the original one, while the rest uses an original algorithm
- (I also do this if I get inspired by an answer in another language than the one I’m using, and I transcribed parts of it into my answer)

#### Post a new answer, without citing the original answer

- If I came up with my answer after looking at the original one, which inspired me to come up with a completely different approach
- If I came up with my answer independently, with no knowledge of other answers (duh)